# View Uploaded file symfony4

Tags: file-upload, view, symfony4

How to view the uploaded file in symfony 4

Refered link:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

It throws error as `Variable "brochure" does not exist.` while viewing the uploaded file

In twig

```
<a href="{{ asset('public/uploads/brochures/' ~ brochure.brochure) }}">View brochure (PDF)</a>
```

here the entity file is brochure and uploaded file name is brochure

Comment: is the file in the uploaded location? recorded in the database?

Comment: yes Deniz Aktruk, it is storing in the right path and also in database

Comment: Maybe if you do it follow you can understand the reason of the error 
   {{dump(brochure)}}